# When I run my Python program, the pygame window opens for a split second then quits

Tags: python, python-2.7, crash, pygame, exit

I'm a beginning programmer trying to make a game using python and pygame from an online course. But when I run the following code, the pygame window opens for a split second, then closes.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900,700))

finished = False

while finished == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            finished = True

    rectOne = pygame.Rect(0,0,30,30)

    color = (0,0,255) #R,G,B
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,rectOne)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I don't get any error messages either. It's like it runs my loop once then changes `finished` to `True`. I've checked lots of times and my code matches the code of the online course exactly. I'm using a Mac and Python 2.7.13. Can anyone help?
Update: I'm not sure if this helps, but I can still run the code below and it works perfectly fine.
    import pygame

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900,700))

finished = False

while finished == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             finished = True
```

Comment: How are you running the code? You may need to run it from a terminal to see any errors.

Comment: When I run your code a window stays open with a blue square in the top left. It doesn't close after a second

Comment: I run it by clicking the run tab and then clicking "run module". It could be my computer.

Comment: Open a terminal window in the directory that contains your .py file and run it by entering `python name_of_your_file.py`. If you see any error messages, post them here.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i have searched about your problem a bit and i came to the conclusion that you need to try the following things:

A) Use `pygame.display.update()` instead of `pygame.display.flip()`

B) Try placing these at the end of your program outside the main loop: `pygame.QUIT` and on the next line `quit()`

C) If none of my above speculations work, then you need to check if the QUIT event is getting triggered automatically, do this by changing your `while` loop as the following:

```
while not finished: 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
       print(event)
```

After this when you run your program, in the Shell it will show the events that occur on the pygame screen, if there is a problem then the first and last event would be QUIT and then it is probably the problem of Mac or the version, because i recently read on reddit about it, check it out [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/4o6g6q/pygame_window_opens_then_closes_immediately/?st=j6dy1bzh&sh=8d18d859)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, none of these worked though. When I printed the events, I got: <Event(4-MouseMotion {'buttons': (0, 0, 0), 'pos': (475, 286), 'rel': (475, 286)})>
<Event(4-MouseMotion {'buttons': (0, 0, 0), 'pos': (466, 290), 'rel': (-9, 4)})>
<Event(4-MouseMotion {'buttons': (0, 0, 0), 'pos': (455, 296), 'rel': (-11, 6)})>   I'm pretty sure it must be a problem with my Mac, and if that is true, I'm wondering if you can answer the question that I will post shortly.